# Physical android device suddenly not found by Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, usb, device

SOLVED, se my own answer below.

While happily developing on my physical phone, Eclipse inexplicably doesn't find it next time I choose run. The Devices view is empty and grayed out. Rebooting doesn't help. Reinstalling googles' USB drivers doesn't help. Reinstalling Kies doesn't help.

Kies and Windows 7 have no problem finding the physical device immediately when I connect it.

What can I do?

Comment: Sounds crazy but try a different USB port, even though there may be nothing wrong with that one, has worked for me. Another thing that can sometimes work is to unplug, toggle USB debugging, and plugging back in to the USB port

Comment: have you tried checking the device's status with adb.exe? Sometimes restarting adb (with the kill-server and start-server switches) will do the trick.

Comment: adb usb gives "error: device not found". In all USB ports. That's progress, thanks! But I've already reinstalled Google USB Driver with the SDK Manager, because it was said somewhere that's how to reinstall ADB. And remember, Win7 finds the phone.

Comment: MTP USB Device, says Win7 device manager is the driver for my mobile device. Is that the right one, or has a Samsung driver or an MS driver sneaked in there? Btw I use a laptop and USB ports occasionally die briefly, but never before selectively for only some software.

Answer (score 1):

Unplugging and reconnecting the device, and restarting Eclipse can solve this problem. Eclipse is quite a random piece of software and likes to misbehave in so many devious ways.

Comment: That's a reflex thing to do when using Eclipse! It doesn't help this time after several attempts. Eclipse has many great features. Unfortunately it is worthless because it doesn't work, so it has a very suitable name... I've installed Android Studio now, faster to migrate to that than to deal with Eclipse's endless issues.

Comment: In this case it wasn't Eclipses' fault. Android Studio doesn't find any device either.

Answer (score 0):

Heureka!
Somehow, the "USB debugging" option on the phone had been disabled. Probably by my own fat fingers. Sorry for having disturbed you. Thanks for your suggestions.